# Flutter: Dart Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'ValueNotifier<int>' of 'function result',

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi can anyone please tell me what is wrong with this code.
I'm trying to create a countdown timer in my widget,

```
class _SaleSuccessDialogState extends State<SaleSuccessDialog> {
  final ValueNotifier<int> counter = ValueNotifier(10);
  Timer? countDownTimer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (App.preferences.kTillLockAfterSale) {
      Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        countDownTimer ??= timer;
        setState(() => counter.value--);
        if (counter.value == 0) {
          timer.cancel();
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: counter,
  builder: (context, counterValue, child) {
    return Text("Counter:$counterValue");
  },
),
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

Dart Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'ValueNotifier' of 'function result'

Comment: Use as Text("Counter:${counter.value}");

Comment: Hm, did you try a clean start? Because your snippet works for me ..

Comment: Works for me as well. Two tips: indicate the type of your notifier like `ValueListenableBuilder<int>` and you don't need `setState` here, just simply `counter.value--;`.